# concatenate date and time in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that imports events from spreadsheets into calendar:

```
function caltest1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 3;   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var title = row[0];  // First column
    var desc = row[1];       // Second column
    var tstart = row[2];
    var tstop = row[3];
    var loc = row[4];
    //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010     09:00:00"), {description:desc,location:loc});
    cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc});
 }
}
```

The script works fine if my spreadsheet contains the data like:

```
Title      Description    Start               Stop                  Channel
Mr Dear    no drinks      5/6/2014 20:55:00   5/6/2014 21:57:00     what ever
```

But it does not work if I create my own date =CONCATENATE($D4, " ",$G4), given that D4 has a date and G4 has time combined into a single cell Date and time. I figured because it senses that concatenate creates a plain text and not a time formatting, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In spreadsheets, dates have a native value of an integer representing the number of days since december 31 1899 and time is a decimal value which is the fraction of a day ( 6 hours = 1/4 of a day for example , 0.25 day).

So when you add **DATE+TIME** (integer+decimal) in a spreadsheet you get a full date with time .

So the answer (as you noticed it in your comment on the other answer) is logically to **ADD** both values. That's actually the reason spreadsheets are build like that ! (to make it easy to use date and time)

Use the formula `=D2+E2` in a new column and you get a complete date object directly useable in JavaScript.

In Javascript date and time are the same objects, there is no time object that has no date and no date without time : their native values are milliseconds counted from January 1 1970 at midnight (which is an integer).

Comment: Since there are some more answers that seem to be wrong, here's a sample formula as an example: =DATE(2018,3,29) + TIME(21,17,19)

Comment: In my casem separator is ; not sure in other locales:
`=DATE(2018;3;29) + TIME(21;17;19)`

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of concatenated strings is text, you can convert them to date before calling the Calendar methods.

```
var tstart = new Date(row[2]);
var tstop = new Date(row[3]);
```

Comment: I am not too sure if you gave a correct alternative by correcting the code itself, but I found the solution by replacing bogus concatenate function with =D2 + E2, simple function that does the trick and convert the data into a proper date and time. For some reason concatenate function borrows its formatting from it's predeceasing cells and does not recognize its own cell's formatting! Which is not working well for me as I am getting data from my form and passing it down to Calendar, so unless it's in a proper format it will not work.and concatenate sucks at it.

Answer (score -1):

I successfully concatenated date and time by using 
    `=text(A2,"dd/mm/yy") & ", " & text(B2,"HH:MM")`

[I concatenated date and time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlxvI.png)

Comment: too bad it needs to be done in Google Script. I am not going to -1 but your answer is no applicable here.