# Google Script: Sheets working hours data to Events in Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have my working hours in a Sheets document that I want to use to make Events in Calendar.

Following the tutorial:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/g-suite-pro-tip-how-to-automatically-add-a-schedule-from-google-sheets-into-calendar

I have this script:

```
function scheduleShifts() {
/**
 Task 1) Open the event calendar
**/
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

/** Task 2) Pull each shift information into the code, in a form that the code can understand
**/

var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("E2:F100").getValues();

/**
Create the calender entry
**/
for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
  var shift = signups[x];

  eventName = "Work hours";
  var startTime = shift[0];
  var endTime = shift[1];

  eventCal.createEvent(eventName, startTime, endTime); }
}
```

But, I get the error:

```
Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent.
scheduleShifts  @ Code.gs:24
```

Because I do not work everyday, there are blank cells in the data range from Sheets, could this be the issue?
And how can I ask the script to ignore those cells within that data range that are blank and NOT to create an event for them?

My work hours are provided with times and dates in seperate columns, so I used this Sheet formula to convert the data to DateTime format, and placed into new cells in columns E and F:

`=IF(C2 <> "",concatenate(text(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy")&" "&text(C2,"hh:mm:ss")),"")`

`=IF(D2 <> "",concatenate(text(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy")&" "&text(D2,"hh:mm:ss")),"")`

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29/11/2021 | man | 13:30 | 22:30 | 29/11/2021 13:30:00 | 29/11/2021 22:30:00 |
| 30/11/2021 | tir |  |  |  |  |
| 01/12/2021 | ons |  |  |  |  |
| 02/12/2021 | tor | 09:30 | 16:42 | 02/12/2021 09:30:00 | 02/12/2021 16:42:00 |
| 03/12/2021 | fre | 09:30 | 16:42 | 03/12/2021 09:30:00 | 03/12/2021 16:42:00 |
| 04/12/2021 | lør |  |  |  |  |
| 05/12/2021 | søn |  |  |  |  |
| 06/12/2021 | man | 09:30 | 16:30 | 06/12/2021 09:30:00 | 06/12/2021 16:30:00 |
| 07/12/2021 | tir | 09:30 | 18:30 | 07/12/2021 09:30:00 | 07/12/2021 18:30:00 |

My understanding is using .getValues ignores the formula and only delivers the value of the cell, so I don't believe this to be the issue, but I thought I had better mention it for full disclosure.

Comment: arguments for both start and end time must be dates, not strings. The concatenate formula you are using is not the right approach. See my answer here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23508261/concatenate-date-and-time-in-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

The method is [createEvent(String,Date,Date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date))

You are sending `createEvent(String,String,String)`

You need to parse your sting into a date.

```
// Creates an event for the moon landing and logs the ID.
var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',
    new Date('July 20, 1969 20:00:00 UTC'),
    new Date('July 21, 1969 21:00:00 UTC'));
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
```